# Procedure for Deploy/Host Provider Host App in on-premises MS SharePoint 2013 Team/Developer Site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

> I'm often getting error while hosting provider host app, **kindly share me the exact procedure to host provider host app in on-premises SharePoint 2013 team/developer site.**

Is Certificate mandatory for provider host app?

Answer (score 0):

Certificate is mandatory, you can go with SelfSigned Certificate.

Are you trying to setup Development environment, or you are doing it in Production?

Entire setup requires Service Application setup, Domain name creation and several steps, as you must be aware. There is [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179923.aspx) for same, and a [blog by Andrew Connell](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Fully-Scripted-Solution-for-Creating-and-Registering-Self-Signed-Certs-for-SP2013-High-Trust-Apps-with-S2S-Trust), which details doing configuration using PowerShell.

There is another beautiful [article by Critical Path Training](https://www.criticalpathtraining.com/articles/critical-path-training-sharepoint-server-2013-virtual-machine-setup-guide/) site, for which you need to register (Free).